# Constraint enforcing the existence of rows for each row in another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-modeling

Suppose the following system:

There are factories that are building cars. Each factory defines colors in which they produce the cars. When a new model comes, it gets assigned to a factory. At the same time, the factory has to produce this model in all of the colors this particular factory defines.

The database I came up with so far:

```
table Factories {
   id PRIMARY KEY
}

table ChosenColors {
   factory_id
   color: string

   UNIQUE(factory_id, color)
   FK(factory_id) -> Factories(id)
}

table Models {
   id PRIMARY KEY
   factory_id

   FK(factory_id) -> Factories(id)
}

table ProducedCars {
   id PRIMARY KEY
   model_id
   color: string

   FK(model_id) -> Models(id)
}
```

Now, I would like to add the following constraint:
"Each model must have a related produced car for each chosen color of the factory that is supposed to produce this model"

In other words, creating a new row in the model table would take the following within one transaction:

- insert `factory_id` into models
- select all chosen colors of `factory_id`
- for each `color` selected in the previous step, insert `model_id` and `color` into produced cars

Is there a way to write an integrity constraint in SQL which would enforce a produced car to always exist, according to the rules described above? A trigger will not help me, I am not only interested in inserting correct data, but also to keep the data consistent through all future updates/deletes. I am using PostgreSQL.

Also, if this is a known problem that I do not know how to call, feel free to link any related resources, I will be grateful.

Comment: Short answer: no. Relational constraints among multiple table rows are limited to PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, and FOREIGN KEY. None of those apply to your use case.

Comment: It sounds like you want `ProducedCars` to be a `view`. The fact you can do it this way is the reason why your requirement to have it in a `table` is not feasible in SQL; why would anyone implement a solution so complex and detrimental to performance when a simple alternative exists? Related note: "*A trigger will not help me*" is not enough of an explanation; triggers would be able to do what you say with a `table` so you need to explain **why** you think that.